# efficient inversion of known CDF in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, probability-density

I need to compute efficiently and in a numerically stable way the inverse CDF F^-1(y) (cumulative distribution function) of a probability function, assuming that both the PDF f(x) and the CDF F(x) are known analytically but the inverse CDF is not. I am doing this in MATLAB.

This is a root-finding problem for F(x)-y and I could use *fzero*:

```
invcdf = @(y, x0) fzero(@(x) cdf(x) - y, x0);
```

However, *fzero* is for a generic nonlinear function.

I wonder if there is some function, or I can write some algorithm that uses the explicit information that F(x) is a cdf (for example, we know that it is monotonically non-decreasing and we have its derivative, f(x)).

FYI, the shape of the PDFs I am working with is generic mixtures of Gaussian distributions multiplied by a polynomial of arbitrary degree (the CDF can be computed analytically in this case, although it's not pretty and it becomes expensive for polynomials with many terms). Note that I need to compute the inverse CDF for millions of CDFs within this class; a lookup table is not feasible.

For more mathematical details see also [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728806/efficient-and-stable-computation-of-inverse-cdf) on Math Exchange (here I am asking specifically for a MATLAB solution).

Comment: Can you give the form of the pdf / cdf? One way to invert the CDF, knowing that it is increasing from 0 to 1, is to compute a lookup table and interpolate values in between.

Comment: @k1next: Sure, added some details in the question. A lookup table wouldn't work well here as I need to compute this for millions of different CDFs in the same class, I never use a single CDF more than once or twice.

Comment: So more or less, for each CDF, you need CDF^-1 evaluated only at a single (or few) points, but for a lot of different CDF? Note, that for special types of CDFs there exists the `icdf` command.

Comment: Yes. This is part of a Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) method. I don't know the CDFs beforehand, so the capacity for parallelization is limited. I don't think that icdf supports "mixture of normals multiplied by polynomials of arbitrary degree".

Comment: Would a bisection method work?

Comment: Sure, it would. My question is to know what would be the state-of-the-art here in terms of efficiency and precision. I am aware of a few textbook numerical algorithms for root finding (see my link to Math Exchange). For example, *fzero* as far as I know implements Brent's method, which does not use the derivative nor the knowledge that the CDF is monotonic.

Comment: You might find that [SciComp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com) is a better fit for this question.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right. I've lost track of the many Stack Exchanges by now.